# Export VBO and import in other Blueprism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I'm new in RPA and also in BluePrism. I've been developing some objects in order to use it in other machine. The problem is that my computer has version 6.6 and the other one a lower version (6.4). I've tried to export obejct (in XML format) and as a release. But I have the same result... When I import it in the other machine, all the nodes are together in the same position (giving me extra errors). Is there a way to export an object that can be readble for older versions of bp?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7HcW.png)

Comment: In the image you can see that all the 'nodes'/'elements' used are placed in the same position when I open it in the other BluePrism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact phenomenon is well documented in [this Blue Prism Community post](https://community.blueprism.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=e72e66eb-92cf-4acf-add9-7dba6f6486bd&CommunityKey=1b679a41-ef27-4557-a2dd-9af040812654&tab=digestviewer). Your issue is likely that Blue Prism changed the way that XML is generated by the client between v6.3 and v6.6, thus leading to the "stacked" appearance of your object/process stages. The user in the linked thread implied that un-stacking the stages seems to do the trick here.

More broadly: exports and releases are *somewhat* backward-compatible; that is, they should work, but aren't guaranteed between releases that change the XML spec of exported processes/objects/releases.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll look for that. Thanks a lot for your time